# How do I whitelist access to a PostgreSQL schema?

Tags: postgresql, access-control, whitelist

I have a certain schema in a PG database that contains some very sensitive data. I'd like to prevent access to it for every role except one, but I can't figure it out from the documentation on permissions.

To begin with, I figured I'd only give `CONNECT` access to that one special role, but then every other role can connect to the schema. To make things worse, every role can also `CREATE`, `DROP`, and do everything else.

What have I missed?

Side question: in time, this schema will be a streaming destination from another instance of postgresql. In short, we have a master db server that supports a live web site, and we need a secondary, read-only copy of it on another machine to perform some computationally intensive queries on. We figured that streaming was the answer. Does this make sense? Is it still possible to protect access to it?

We are using version 9.5, in case this is relevant.

Comment: The privilege to connect to a database is granted by default to the role `public` you need to revoke: `revoke connect from public` then you can control which user is allowed to connect through grants`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` and put this content:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             YOUR_USER       [USER_IP]/32            md5
```

It will allow connections with a password for this specific user from this specific LAN/WAN IP.

Only this user and `postgres` will be allowed.

> in time, this database will be a streaming destination from another instance of postgresql.

When this database becomes a replication master you can add the following to the same file:

```
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     REPL_USER        [REPL_HOST]/32            md5
```

More info on how to set up the replication here: https://www.gab.lc/articles/replication_postgresql

After the changes you need to reload PostgreSQL with:

```
service postgresql reload
```

You can drop the roles you don't want to allow.

**Update:**

If you wish to revoke privileges with a query you can run:

```
-- Grant privileges to whitelisted user:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database name] TO [good_user];

-- Revoke privileges for other users:
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON [database name] FROM [bad_user];
```

Comment: Uhm, I guess I should have said schema rather than database, sorry. (I edited the question)

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to revoke privileges with a query

Comment: Updated again to show how to whitelist allowed user

Comment: Thanks @Gab. Does that mean that I essentially have to manually blacklist every `bad_user` when I create new ones?

Comment: You do have to manually set privileges for each user. If you want `user_a` to have new privileges and `user_b` to have privileges revoked you will have to do it manually

Comment: I also found this: `REVOKE connect ON DATABASE database_name FROM PUBLIC;
GRANT connect ON DATABASE database_name TO rolename;` which seems better suited. Does this do what I think it does?

Comment: It will revoke connection but not all privileges. In the end its fairly similar since without connecting you can't do anything

Comment: I suppose you are right, I should also revoke/grant other privileges to be extra safe. Thanks.